# "Никто(,) кроме нас"

Tags: пунктуация

Попалось в газете название клуба бывших афганцев "Никто кроме нас". Именно так, без запятых. Правильно ли это, или запятая тут все-таки нужна?
Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это тема ограничительно-расширительных членов предложения, которые  имеют значение включения, исключения и замещения  и являются падежными формами существительных или местоимений с наречными предлогами  КРОМЕ, ПОМИМО, ИСКЛЮЧАЯ, ВКЛЮЧАЯ, ЗА ИСКЛЮЧЕНИЕМ, СВЕРХ, НАРЯДУ.

Эти обороты практически всегда выделяются запятыми (исключением является вариант со словом ВМЕСТО, который  в некоторых случаях может не обособляться, например:  Вместо лампы пришлось воспользоваться свечкой). В устной речи обороты  выделяются паузами и интонационным ударением.

Но всё это касается предложений, а в нашем случае  выражение «Никто кроме нас» имеет назывной характер и обозначает группу лиц (можно сравнить: дети вместе с родителями).

Произношение без паузы, и я думаю, что запятая не нужна.

Answer (score 5):

Вообще-то этот оборот всегда выделялся факультативно.Оборот может обособляться в зависимости от смысловой нагрузки, положения в предложении, степени распространённости и др., то есть в том случае, если автор хочет выделить такие обороты по смыслу и интонационно:"Никто, кроме нас"- оборот со значением исключения, нужно выделять.

В последнее время наблюдается тенденция к выделению оборотов с кроме независимо от оттенков значения. Особенно часто это происходит:

а) при наличии отрицательных местоимений никто, ничего и вопросительных местоимений кто, что...- здесь как раз такой случай, запятая нужна.

[Уточняющие, пояснительные и присоединительные члены предложения, их обособление | licey.net](http://licey.net/russian/syntax/r1_2_8)

Answer (score 0):

Запятые могут не ставиться, если предлог «кроме» имеет значение «дополнительно, вдобавок к чему-либо».