# Он ничего не делал(,) кроме добра

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, запятые

По правилам, **кроме** почти всегда выделяется запятыми. Но в этом случае правила не совсем работают. Если акцент делается на том, что он ничего не делал (на ничегонеделании), то, конечно, здесь **кроме**  имеет значение "исключения" и нужна запятая. Но мысль именно такая: **делал** только добро: Ничего не делал кроме добра.

- В правилах такой случай не указан. Как его аргументировать грамотно? Просто говорить, что отталкиваюсь от смысла и не ставлю запятой или что тесная связь со сказуемым?

Comment: Похожий вопрос: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/30966/%d0%9d%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%81

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Следует помнить, что выделение таких оборотов не является обязательным! <...>
>   В последнее время наблюдается тенденция к выделению оборотов с *кроме* независимо от оттенков значения. Особенно часто это происходит:
>   а) при наличии отрицательных местоимений никто, ничего и вопросительных местоимений кто, что: Я ничего не мог различить, кроме мутного кручения метели (Пушкин); ([Лицей](http://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/724-28_utochnyayuschie__poyasnitelnye_i_prisoedinitelnye_chleny_predlozheniya.html))

Выбор за Вами. Я бы предпочел следовать указанной тенденции и поставить запятую.